# how to change compromised jenkins node "secret"?

Tags: jenkins

When my jenkins slave starts on its node, the command is run locally from that server:

```
/bin/java  -jar /usr/local/jenkins/slave.jar \
  -jnlpUrl https://example.com/computer/foo/slave-agent.jnlp \
  -secret <big long hex id>
```

The "big long hex id" found its way into a git repository and is now compromised.  How do I tell my jenkins master to change it?

Comment: did you ever figure out a way to do this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the Slave from Jenkins, then re-add it, it should have a new ID assigned to it.

Comment: I tried that first, however it seemed when i recreated the node, it somehow pulled it from a cache of some kind (used the same name) and it had the same identifier still.  will try again.

Comment: Augh.  How about keeping the original Slave, creating a new one.  Then deleting the original one?  Might have to rename the new one back to the original one to keep desired behavior.  And that should (I would hope) muck with the ID cache so it won't reuse the existing one. Completely untested though....

Comment: That sounded promising, but it doesn't work, the secret changes when the node is renamed, and it changes back to the previously exposed secret.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this is using the JNLP protocol and not JNLP4. The classes that generate the secrets: JNLPJnlpSlaveAgentProtocol/JnlpAgentReceiver uses a HMAC which uses the hostname as one input and a secret key as the other input. The secret input is fetched from the "DefaultConfidentialStore" which generates and stores a file in `$JENKINS_HOME/secrets/`. The name for the file in this case is probably: `$JENKINS_HOME/secrets/jenkins.slaves.JnlpSlaveAgentProtocol.secret`

To get a different result you either need to change the hostname or remove that file (a new one will be auto generated).

Links:

https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/security/DefaultConfidentialStore.html

https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/slaves/JnlpAgentReceiver.html